# Octave, Error undefined variable, not recognized data array as input of an function

Tags: octave

all my variables are declared in my main script as you can see below:

```
DataArray.a = 1;  
DataArray.b = 2;
DataArray.c = 3;  
d = 4;  
e = 5;  
f = 6;  

DataArray = test1_2 (DataArray);

disp(DataArray);
```

The main script also works with some functions.
A input of these functions is the data array which is declared in the main script:

```
function DataArray = test1_2 (d, e, f, DataArray )

g = DataArray.a;
h = DataArray.b;

DataArray.result = d * g;
endfunction
```

When I run the main script the following error occurs:

> error: "'DataArray' undefined near line 28 column 5"
> error: called from test1_2 at line 28 column 3

Line 28 is the line: g = DataArray.a

If i type in for example the DataArray.a, octave knows that it is declared and gives out "1".

How can I use the same data array in my main script as well as in my function?

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't pass the data into the function"? I added the code of my function..

Comment: 1) The function `test1_2 ` is defined to have 4 input arguments but you're calling it with just one input. 2) The input arguments `e` and `f` are not used anywhere in the function which make them useless. 3) The variable `h` serves no purpose as it's not used any further and not taken out as output. 4) The error message suggests that there are at least 28 lines  in `test1_2`.  You haven't shown that many lines and we cannot guess your code and find the problem in it. 5) Help us help you by creating a [mcve]

Comment: Thats all of the Programm code, there are only some description lines above from line 1 to 25. I know that there are some variables which are not used but it was only a fast try to explain my Problem.. I will correct it for you

Comment: With the latest changes you have made to your example, there is no error. Does that mean you have resolved the problem on your own or do you still have the same question?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
DataArray = test1_2 (DataArray);
```

Your `test1_2` function is called with one argument. Inside the function:

```
function DataArray = test1_2 (d, e, f, DataArray )
```

only the first argument, `d`, is defined. The other arguments remain undefined. Note that the names of the arguments inside the function are totally unrelated to the names of variables you use to call the function. That is, inside the function, the variable `d` contains whatever `DataArray` contains outside the function, not what is inside the variable `d` outside the function. Octave does not try to match up variable names like this.

So, given that your function needs 4 input arguments, you should call it as this:

```
DataArray = test1_2(d, e, f, DataArray )
```

I suggest you read the excellent tutorials from MATLAB, for example [these about writing functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html). As you know, Octave mostly mimics the MATLAB syntax, so the MATLAB tutorials are also a good way to get started with Octave.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Apart from the smaller misstakes with the variables, my problem is, that octave did not recognize the DataArray in the function. It says: " DataArray.a is a undefined variable" altough it is declared in the main script. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @Manu.l: As I said in the answer, you need to call your function with 4 arguments. I show in the answer how to do this. The function doesn’t see variables defined outside it unless you pass them in as arguments.